# Knockout with computed value return always 'undefined'

Tags: knockout.js

I use this code :

```
function Sample() {
    var self = this;
    self.category = ko.observable();
    self.categoryName = ko.computed(function () {
        var category = self.category();
        console.log(category);
        return category;
    }
}

var s = new Sample();
s.category = 0;
```

if I bind the category property in span for example :

```
<span data-bind="text: categoryName"></span>
```

span is void and console.log return 'undefined' for category

what is wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

observables are functions, so when you set the value of an observable you need to pass the value as the first argument.

So, when you set `category`, you would do:

`s.category(0);`

Comment: Those darn parenthesis :-) ... That's the #1 mistake i people make when they code with KO.